# html form validation combined with flask and python

Tags: python, validation, flask, form-submit

I have a web app that collects some data in text boxes then sends them to a python script that is running with flask

I have found two ways of submitting the form.

my button manages to collect the data and send it of to python and retires the answer from python but does **not** **validate** the inputs

my input tag manages to validate the text buttons but clears the form and does not manage to send the data of to the python script for processing.

I would like to do aspects of both buttons , I would like to validate , send data to python and retired the data.

Any ideas how to combine the function of the input submit and the button into one clickable item that validates and submits?

Any help much appreachiated

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<script type="text/javascript">


  $(function() {
    var submit_form = function(e) {


      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/add_numbers', {
        nm_height: $('input[name="nm_height"]').val(),
        mn_material: $('input[name="mn_material"]').val(),
        lc_height: $('input[name="lc_height"]').val(),
        li6_enrichment_fraction: $('input[name="li6_enrichment_fraction"]').val()

      }, function(data) {
        $('#result').text(data.result);
        $('input[name=nm_height]').focus().select();
      });


      return false;
    };
    $('#calculate').bind('click', submit_form);
    //$("#myform").bind('ajax:complete', submit_form);
    $('input[type=text]').bind('keydown', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        submit_form(e);
      }
    });
    $('input[name=a]').focus();
  });
</script>


<p>
    <form  name="myform" id="myform" >
        <!--<form action="#" method='POST GET'>-->

  <p>Height of neutron multiplier pebble bed <input type="number" size="10" name="nm_height" min="10" max="140"  step="any"  required placeholder='10 to 120'> mm </p>
  <p>Neutron multiplier material <input type="text" size="10" name="mn_material" required placeholder='Be or Be12Ti'> Be or Be12Ti</p>
  <p>Height of lithium ceramic pebble bed  <input type="number" size="10"  name="lc_height"  min="10" max="140"  step="any" required placeholder='1 to 60'> mm </p>
  <p>Lithium 6 enrichment <input type="number" size="10" name="li6_enrichment_fraction"  min="0" max="100"  step="any" required placeholder='60 to 100'> %</p>


   <button id="calculate" type="submit">predict TBR</button>


   <input id="calculate" type="submit"></input>

  </form>

  TBR =<span id="result">?</span>
  <br>
  The TBR is quoted with a 95% <a href='http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/confint.htm'> confidence interval </a>
<!--<p><a href=# id="calculate">calculate server side</a>-->
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this? Am trying to do something similar it might need WTForms http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/wtforms/

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same case and I have decided to use either regular expressions in the validation or just javascript . 
regular expression is more powerful and faster but needs time, javascript is easier and slower. so it is a deal.

Comment: You should never validate data with only javascript. If you would like to validate on the frontend with javascript for usability that's slightly optional, but if you want a secure application you need to validate from the backend (python in this case) too.

Answer (score 0):

Let the backend handle the validation using something like [WTFForms](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Then all you need to worry about is submitting the data to the API endpoint and dealing with the responses that come back.

Avoid doing any validation strictly on the frontend because it's not secure and more likely to be tricked compared to backend validation.

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myform').on('submit', function() {
        var res = $.ajax({
            url: '/add-numbers'
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            ...
        });

        res.done(function(data) {
            // get successful calculation back...
        });

        res.fail(function() {
            // handle validation or calculation errors...
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %
```